# Getting flattened hit data from Google Analytics in Big Query over a range of tables

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

The following is a query to flatten "hit" results piped to BigQuery from Google Analytics:

```
SELECT
*
FROM flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten([ga_sessions_20171116], hits), hits.product), hits.product.customDimensions), hits.product.customMetrics), hits.promotion), hits.experiment), hits.customDimensions), hits.customVariables), hits.customMetrics)
Limit 20
```

How would one do the same across a range of tables, or is that even possible? I tried:

```
SELECT
*
FROM flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten(flatten([ga_sessions_2017111*], hits), hits.product), hits.product.customDimensions), hits.product.customMetrics), hits.promotion), hits.experiment), hits.customDimensions), hits.customVariables), hits.customMetrics)
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0' and '10'
Limit 20
```

But it didn't work. Does anyone know how one would do this?

Comment: I'd recommend to use [standard sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) as solving this becomes much easier. Also, do consider not using `"*"` against GA data, your costs can increase unnecessarily and very likely you don't need the whole dataset in one single query.

Comment: How would I approach solving it with standard sql?

Comment: Use the [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) operator over arrays to flatten it. You can access its data by using aliasing. As for the range of tables, use [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) with filter in `_TABLE_SUFFIX`.

Comment: It'd be a great help if you could provide an example of sorts...

Comment: ```SELECT 
fullvisitorid,
prods.productSku
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) prods
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20171110' and '20171111'
LIMIT 1000```

This flattens `hits`, then `product`.  You can access their data just by referring to the alias and then the field name.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you! That's very concise. So the UNNEST pulls the data in the repeated field into an alias. What then is the type of that alias out of curiosity. It's some sort of object?

Comment: It'll be whatever the element type of the array is. For `hits`, it is a struct with `product` and other fields contained inside. Willian, do you want to post your query as an answer?

Comment: Just did :)! Hopefully it'll be enough for OP to work through all fields he wants in his query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with nested data in [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) is much easier than it is in Legacy (because of query syntax and predictability of behavior).

This being said, do consider using it. Your query in Standard becomes something like:

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid visitor_id,
  prods.productSku sku,
  custd.index index
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) prods,
UNNEST(prods.customDimensions) custd
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20171110' and '20171111'
LIMIT 1000
```

This is just an example but hopefully it's enough to understand the concept.

`hits` is a *repeated* field of *structs* so it's something like:

```
hits = [{'hitNumber': 1, 'product': [{'productSku': 'sku0'}]}, {'hitNumber': 2}, ...]
```

When you apply the `unnest(hits) AS unnested_hits` operation it becomes:

```
unnested_hits = {'hitNumber': 1, 'product': [{'productSku': 'sku0'}]},
                {'hitNumber': 2}
                ...
```

So if you call it `"unnested_hits"`, when you reference to this alias you'll get this flattened data. You can go on such as unnesting the field `product` inside `unnested_hits`).

For a deeper understanding of these concepts, make sure to read through the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays), they are quite well written and you can learn pretty much everything you'll need to work effectively in BigQuery.

As a final note, you are selecting all fields from GA. As the old saying goes, every time someone runs a query of the type `"SELECT * FROM TABLE"` a panda somewhere in the world dies.

You must be very careful to run this type of query in BQ as you'll get billed by volume of processed data; make sure you are bringing only what is absolutely necessary.